# What is the probability that in five dealt cards, exactly two cards will have the same value?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I tried using a Binomial Probability Distribution, but I can't seem to get the correct answer, which according to my textbook, is approximately $0.4226$. I use my calculator to find the Binompdf but I need to know the probability of getting one pair. 
My textbook said it was $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3$, but I can't understand where or why they got the $\binom{4}{2}$ and the $\binom{4}{1}^3$.

Comment: From a standard 52 cards deck?

Comment: By value, I assume you mean "rank"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry if I didn't make it clear, I meant the number on the card.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, a standard deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hand has four different ranks. There are $\binom{13}{4}$ ways to choose those ranks. There are four ways to pick the rank that has two cards. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the two cards of the same rank, and $4^3$ ways to choose the three other cards.

So this gives $$\binom{13}{4}\cdot 4\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 4^3$$

different hands, out of $\binom{52}{5}$ total hands.

This gives you a probability:

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\frac{13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10}{4!}\cdot 4^4\cdot 6}{\frac{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}{5!}} &=\frac{5\cdot 13\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 4^4\cdot 6}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}\\
&=\frac{11\cdot 4^2\cdot 6}{51\cdot 49}
\end{align}$$

Other techniques require care that you avoid hands with more than two cards of the same rank, or two cards of the same rank but another pair. This technique uses a "trick" - that a hand with exactly one pair has exactly four ranks, and visa versa.